# how to make elements inside a div span on multiple lines

Tags: reactjs, components

so i just have these divs:

so basically i have created these divs from one component to another just like this and i have multiple text like this and i want each one of them to span on multiple lines. example: first div will have last blood pressure on one line, 90/60 on another and so on
my code:

card.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../Card/Card.css'


function card ({type,value,subValue,date}) {
    return (
        <div 
        type={type}
        value = {value}
        subValue = {subValue}
        date = {date}
        className={type === "Last Blood Pressure" ? "blood-pressure" : 
        type === "Last Body Weight" ? "Body-Weight":
        type === "Last SpO2" ? "SpO2":
        type === "Last Glucose"?"Glucose":""}
        >
            {type}
            {value}
            {subValue}
            {date}
    </div>  
    )
}
export default card;
```

overview.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from '../../components/widgets/Card/Card';
import '../../pages/Overview/Overview.css';

const Overview = (props) => {

    const measurment = [{ type: "Last Blood Pressure", value: "90/60",subValue:"85 BPM",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"},
    { type: "Last Body Weight", value: "154",subValue:"13% Fat",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"},
    { type: "Last SpO2", value: "98%",subValue:"85 BPM",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"},
    { type: "Last Glucose", value: "200",subValue:"",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"}
]

    return (
        measurment.map(measurment => {
            return (
                <div className = "cards">
                        <Card
                        type={measurment.type} 
                        value={measurment.value}
                        subValue={measurment.subValue}
                        date={measurment.date}
                        className={measurment.className}
                        />
                </div>
                    )
                }
        )
    )
}
export default Overview;
```

overview.css:

```
.cards{
    margin:1em;
    cursor:pointer;
    height: 90px;
    width:170px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* display:inline-block; */
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #57c0e8;
    padding-left: 0.4rem;
    padding-top: 0.3rem;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Stick each one in a paragraph, or a div,..  eg. `<div>{type}<div><div>{value}</div>`  etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put under `paragraph` tag what text you want to appear on next line

```
<p>{type}</p>
<p>{value}</p>
<p>{subValue}</p>
<p>{date}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping everything else just the same add break rules in between your texts like this and it should work fine

```
 {type}
 <br />
 {value}
 <br />
 {subValue}
 <br />
 {date}
```